# Percentage of quarter passed

Tags: date, tableau-api, calculated-field

I'm trying to create a calculated field which shows what percentage of the quarter has passed so far. This is what I have come up with:

```
DATEDIFF('day',DATETRUNC('quarter',[Max Date in quarter]),[Max Date in quarter]) //days past in the quarter so far

/

//total days in quarter
IF (DATEPART('quarter', TODAY()) = 1) THEN
    DATEDIFF('day', #2019-01-01#, #2019-03-31#)
ELSEIF (DATEPART('quarter', TODAY()) = 2) THEN
    DATEDIFF('day', #2019-04-01#, #2019-06-30#)
ELSEIF (DATEPART('quarter', TODAY()) = 3) THEN
    DATEDIFF('day', #2019-07-01#, #2019-09-30#)
ELSEIF (DATEPART('quarter', TODAY()) = 4) THEN
    DATEDIFF('day', #2019-10-01#, #2019-12-31#)
END
```

`[Max Date in Quarter]` looks like:

```
{ FIXED YEAR([Yyyy Mm Dd]), DATETRUNC('quarter',[Yyyy Mm Dd]): MAX([Yyyy Mm Dd])}
```

However, it doesn't seem to work as expected. For `Q1 2019` I get `97.8%` and for `Q2 2019` I get `98.9%`. I would expect both to be 100%.

Additionally, is there a way I could dynamically update the year so when it's 2020, I won't get caught up and need to manually change the dates here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved the correct percentage by using the below:

```
//days past in the quarter so far
IF (DATEPART('quarter', [Max Date in quarter]) = 1) THEN
    DATEDIFF('day', #2019-01-01#, today())
ELSEIF (DATEPART('quarter', [Max Date in quarter]) = 2) THEN
    DATEDIFF('day', #2019-04-01#, today())
ELSEIF (DATEPART('quarter', [Max Date in quarter]) = 3) THEN
    DATEDIFF('day', #2019-07-01#, today())
ELSEIF (DATEPART('quarter', [Max Date in quarter]) = 4) THEN
    DATEDIFF('day', #2019-10-01#, today())
END

/

//total days in quarter
IF (DATEPART('quarter', [Max Date in quarter]) = 1) THEN
    DATEDIFF('day', #2019-01-01#, [Max Date in quarter])
ELSEIF (DATEPART('quarter', [Max Date in quarter]) = 2) THEN
    DATEDIFF('day', #2019-04-01#, [Max Date in quarter])
ELSEIF (DATEPART('quarter', [Max Date in quarter]) = 3) THEN
    DATEDIFF('day', #2019-07-01#, [Max Date in quarter])
ELSEIF (DATEPART('quarter', [Max Date in quarter]) = 4) THEN
    DATEDIFF('day', #2019-10-01#, [Max Date in quarter])
END
```